# SVG clippath with image and fill

Tags: html, svg

My goal is to `fill` the background of the SVG with the `#2590eb` color. I don't know why it is not working. The picture is transparent png. Tried resizing the picture to smaller width but it doesn't work. Any help would be much appreciated.

```html
              <svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">

                <clipPath id="clip-path" transform="translate(292.7 145.85)">
                  <path d="M189.3 52.1C189.3 166.7 94.7 333.3 -21.3 333.3C-137.3 333.3 -274.7 166.7 -274.7 52.1C-274.7 -62.5 -137.3 -125 -21.3
               -125C94.7 -125 189.3 -62.5 189.3 52.1" fill="#2590eb" >
                </clipPath>
             <!-- xlink:href for modern browsers, src for IE8- -->
             <image clip-path="url(#clip-path)" xlink:href="https://www.pngplay.com/wp-content/uploads/7/Happy-Person-Transparent-Background.png" x='50'  src="https://www.pngplay.com/wp-content/uploads/7/Happy-Person-Transparent-Background.png" alt="Image" height="500" width="500" class="svgImg">       
               
             </svg>
```

Comment: A clipPath just clips things, it either clips or it doesn't. Are you looking for a mask instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the filled path is used inside the clipPath you can't see it. In the next example I'm using the path with use before the image element.

Also I've eliminated the transforms you have by changing the viewBox of the svg element.

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="-292.7 -145.85 500 500">

  <clipPath id="clip-path">
    <path id="thePath" d="M189.3 52.1C189.3 166.7 94.7 333.3 -21.3 333.3C-137.3 333.3 -274.7 166.7 -274.7 52.1C-274.7 -62.5 -137.3 -125 -21.3 -125C94.7 -125 189.3 -62.5 189.3 52.1" fill="#2590eb" />
  </clipPath>

  <use xlink:href="#thePath" />

  <image clip-path="url(#clip-path)" xlink:href="https://www.pngplay.com/wp-content/uploads/7/Happy-Person-Transparent-Background.png" x='-300' y="-150" height="500" width="500" class="svgImg" />

</svg>
```